# How to perform aggregate query with where condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this MongoDB query:

```
var array=[]; //some string values

collection.aggregate(
    { $match: { '_id': { $in : array } } }
)
```

But this is not returning any results. How do I perform this?

Comment: you are missing brackets. Correct syntax is collection.aggregate([ { $match: { '_id': { $in : array } } }]). See https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/aggregation/ for details

Comment: Use ObjectID values instead

Comment: its not working with []

Comment: Can you show us the actual string values in the array? As @Sammaye pointed out, you need to use actual `ObjectId` values instead of just some string values and if you only have an array of valid hex string value representations of the `ObjectId` then you need to map the list to cast them to `ObjectId`s and then run the aggregation operation with the brackets as suggested by felix in the first comment.

Comment: Its an array of hex string values
ex :["57f36e94517f72bc09ee761e"]

Comment: use with `ObjectID` for mongoClient `[ObjectId("57f36e94517f72bc09ee761e")] ` but no need if you used in `mongoose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your `array` variable is an array of hex string values `ex :["57f36e94517f72bc09ee761e"]` and for mongo shell, you need to first cast those string values to [**`ObjectId`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)s. Use the JavaScript **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**
method to accomplish the casting in a list.

For example:

**mongo shell**

```
var array = ["585808969e39db5196444c07", "585808969e39db5196444c06"];
var ids = array.map(function(id){ return ObjectId(id); });
```

which you can then query using the aggregate function as in the following

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in" : ids } } }
])
```

The above is essentially the same as

```
db.collection.find({ "_id": { "$in": ids } })
```

**Node.js**

```
var {ObjectId} = require('mongodb'); // or ObjectID
var ids = array.map(id => ObjectId.isValid(id) ? new ObjectId(id) : null;);
```